# How to control Hitechnic motors with ev3 brick

Tags: controls, lego-mindstorms-ev3

Ev3 and hitechnic motor control. I have a problem that I bought hitechnic motors and also adapters for the motors. But when connecting the motors to the ev3 hub, they do not appear on the display as motors, but the signal can be sent to the motors and the speed can be regulated with an unregulated motors.The second problem is that when I try to run the motor on the pid, they always do what I don't need and also exceed their given speed.

Give me the best advice